# Why does this integral blow up?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following integral:

$$ \frac{1}{\gamma^2}\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{t}{\gamma}-\frac{|t-\tau|}{\mu}\right) \left(t-\frac{t^2}{2\gamma}\right)dt = \frac{\gamma/\mu}{(1-\gamma/\mu)^3}e^{-\tau/\mu} $$

for any $\tau>0$. The solution reflects that the integral blows up when $\gamma = \mu$.

Could someone explain why? What is the mechanism of the blow-up?

Comment: Are the signs correct inside the exponential?

Comment: Is it because when y=u, you get 1/(0^3)e. 1/0 ~ $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, the signs are correct.

Comment: The given integral is convergent even if $\gamma=\mu>0$. Do you mind to check carefully the formula please?

Comment: I checked again it's correct.

Comment: https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/1a5115cd-fdd7-48a1-be59-840f2373f017#sidebar=compute

Comment: @adamG It say that I have no access to that page

Answer (score 0):

You must consider to solve:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp{\left(-\frac{t}{\gamma}-\frac{|t-\tau|}{\mu}\right)}\left(t-\frac{t^2}{2\gamma}\right)dt=\int_{0}^{\tau}\exp{\left(-\frac{t}{\gamma}-\frac{\tau-t}{\mu}\right)}\left(t-\frac{t^2}{2\gamma}\right)dt+\int_{\tau}^{\infty}\exp{\left(-\frac{t}{\gamma}-\frac{t-\tau}{\mu}\right)}\left(t-\frac{t^2}{2\gamma}\right)dt$$
You see that the first and second integrals are convergent even if $\gamma=\mu>0$

For the case $\mu=\gamma=\frac{1}{\eta}$
$$I=\exp{(-\eta\tau)}\left(\tau^2+\frac{\tau^2}{3}\eta\right)-\frac{1}{4\eta^2}\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left[\frac{\exp{(-2\tau\eta\alpha)}}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left(\frac{\exp{(-2\tau\eta\alpha)}}{\alpha}\right)\right]_{\alpha=1}$$
Hope I did not any mistake.